# Conditionally attaching jQuery plugin functions to elements on the site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach a jQuery plugin function to an element on my site that exists only on one page. Currently, I'm using this conditional to prevent triggering the `limiter` function and throwing an error when there is no `#advertiser_co_desc` in view.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var elem = $('#charNum');
    if ($('#advertiser_co_desc').length) {
        $('#advertiser_co_desc').limiter(180, elem);        
    }
});
```

On my website `#advertiser_co_desc` is present only on one page.

My solution does the job, but my qualm stems from the fact that the jQuery plugin code as well as the plugin function call presented above (they are both in the same file) get fetched by the browser and the condition is continuously evaluated regardless of whether a user ever gets to a page where `#advertiser_co_desc` exists.

Is the method I'm using optimal, or is there a better way to attach this particular JS only to the page where '#advertiser_co_desc` exists? Naturally, I wan to avoid adding my scripts in the same file with the PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and optimal way to check existence of an element by jquery, is `$('#advertiser_co_desc').length` that you have used already. So no need to change your code.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can wrap the plugin method as,

```
var _limiter = $.fn.limiter;

$.fn.limiter = function(limit, element) { // provide complete argmuments
    if(this.length) {
        _limiter.call(limit, element);
    }
};
```

Make sure that plugin is loaded before this statements.

Comment: This is a very interesting solution.